# Simplest Webservice in Delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to develop a minimalistic webservice.
It should have 2 functions:

1. `senduserdata` (a remote app will call "senduserdata" to send info about users, like "ID" and "amount")
2. `sendconfirmation` (a remote app will tell "all ok for proccess `ID`=X, notes are: `NOTES`)

In past I did a `SOAP` dll that needs `IIS` to run, since deployment is crucial in my case and IIS is not always available is it possible to have a standalone exe that exposes the `SOAP` (or `REST`) interface?

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for external libraries or a way to do it with what is bundled. RemObjects have a nice paid for solution that will function both as an ISAPI DLL and as a standalone application. A long time ago I did some work with Indy but I think that you will need to do something yourself there. It looks like Datasnap also has a solution http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41305. Maybe also take a look at Delphi Web Script (DWS). They might have something.

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with http://xxm.sf.net/ especially with REST (since SOAP support in xxm still needs some work).

Comment: Another option, very close e.g. to WCF is RestFul Json http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Interface-based-services

Comment: Here you can find some good advices and alternatives

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended

Comment: It seems like RemObjects (or DataSnap) could be the tool that I need. Since RemObjects is much simpler to try than Datasnap (for a Delphi professional user) I will start with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeded in a few minutes using the RemObjects trial and setting SOAP as communication protocol in a server + client project group (note: i need server only).

With a VCL EXE i can deploy much easier (i have lots of customers, and accessing their IIS to install a dll it is sometimes too hard).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any TCP library for Delphi which includes a HTTP server, for example [Internet Direct (Indy)](http://www.indyproject.org). With Indy, you can create a stand-alone application (or better, a windows service) without IIS.

In a RESTful web application, the `senduserdata` command would be implemented by a URL like

```
    http://example.com/api/users
```

The clients then use a HTTP [PUT](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html) or [PATCH](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html) request to update the `users` resource.

A senduserdate call for user id 774422 would be written like

```
    LStream := TStringStream.Create('{ "amount":100.50, "currency":"EUR" }');
    try
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
      try
        HTTP.Put('http://example.com/api/users/774422', LStream);
      finally
        HTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      LStream.Free;
    end;
```

In the the Delphi application for server side, a `TIdHTTPServer` component then listens for HTTP requests for the /rest/users resource and in the OnCommandOther event handler it would extract the request body string, parse it, and apply the changes to the user with the ID given in the resource path (/774422).

Comment: ... IMHO not a good advice to reinvent the weel. Building a Rest server is much more than returning some'hello world' content over http.

Comment: Great approach for those ones, who want to stay away from SOAP stuff and its nasty-long and overheaded envelopes. RESTful stuff on Indy rules!